# Why is the MIME-type of a Rust program application/x-sharedlib?

Tags: c++, binary, rust, mime-types

I've got two Hello World programs, written in C++ and Rust:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}
```

**main.rs**

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello World!");
}
```

I compiled both of them using these commands:

```
g++ main.cpp -o Test.bin
```

and

```
rustc main.rs -o Test-Rust.bin
```

Checking for the MIME-type of the C++ binary returned an executable, as I expected:

```
$ file --mime-type Test.bin 
Test.bin: application/x-executable
```

But the Rust binary appears to be a shared library:

```
$ file --mime-type Test-Rust.bin 
Test-Rust.bin: application/x-sharedlib
```

Why does the Rust compiler not output a plain application like `g++` does?

Comment: If this is actually a dup then at least these indicated one cannot answer op's question.